# How to install Nodejs 8.12 in alpine:3.8?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am writing a Dockerfile to dockerize a sample nodejs app. I developed that in `Nodejs v8.12` and `npm 6.4.1`. I know that I can use `node:8.12-alpine` image to get results. But I am using `alpine:3.8` image which is officially recommended.

My Dockerfile contents are below if I use that to build image I will end up in downloading latest version of nodejs from alpine repo. I don't want that to happen, So I planned to install the package manually for the purpose of reproducible. The saddest part is I am unable to find apk version of `Nodejs v8.12` and `npm`.

Can any one help me on where can I find apk for `Nodejs v8.12` or how to install this version of Nodejs to my image manually?

`FROM alpine:3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 9001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]`

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/526c6e618300bdda0da4b3159df682cae83e14aa/8/alpine/Dockerfile), it's already alpine3.8 & nodejs8.12.0

Comment: Thank you @lagom for your effort! unfortunately that doesn't give me output at all. With that link in git I am unable to build an image, if I give `docker build -t my-image .` my terminal is running for a long time and `com.docker.hyperkit` shoots up to 250% usage. Can you please let me know how to alter my Dockerfile with the help of the above reference file? I might have used wrongly.

Answer (score 39):

The question already answered but today I was facing issue so this is how i build with nodejs 8 in Alpine

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/ nodejs=8.9.3-r1
```

You can find node 8 in Alpine repo v3.7

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.7

[image]

you can find node version details [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=edge&repo=main), branch convention is v3.x

Answer (score 3):

Taking references from : https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node

```
FROM alpine:3.8

ENV NODE_VERSION 8.12.0

RUN addgroup -g 1000 node \
    && adduser -u 1000 -G node -s /bin/sh -D node \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        binutils-gold \
        curl \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libgcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        python \
  # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-team
  && for key in \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE \
    77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
    8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && cd "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -Rf "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt

ENV YARN_VERSION 1.9.4

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-yarn curl gnupg tar \
  && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && apk del .build-deps-yarn

CMD [ "node" ]
```

Comment: Thank you @yodebu for your effort! unfortunately that doesn't give me output at all. With that link in git I am unable to build an image, if I give `docker build -t tag-name .` my terminal is running for a long time and `com.docker.hyperkit` shoots up to 250% usage. Can you please let me know how to alter my Dockerfile with the help of the above reference file? I might have used wrongly.

Comment: Hi @Karthick, this should take some time and cpu usage should go high as, here nodejs is built from source. You should wait for the build to happen and you can use the same image or a reference image to build your Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @Karthick, can you provide a strace or a dump of the process running? Googling around, I see alot of Mac users facing the same issue while using docker.

Comment: Thank you @yodebu unfortunately I can't provide you the strace because the length is so long. If you can give me your email I think I can send you out. So apart from this isn't there any other way to install nodejs8.12 in alpine 3.8, like installing through some other tools or do I have to generate apk for nodejs?

Comment: Hi @Karthick I think `node8.12 alpine` image is built on top of `alpine3.8` :) That should work fine.

Comment: I am about to complete my requirement, from the above reference I composed a Dockerfile. But after the execution of command `apk del .build-deps` I get errors like `Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/node/bin/node)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/node/bin/node)
Error relocating /opt/node/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found` and that goes on. Can you pls help me to identify the error.

Comment: Hi @Karthick, this looks like the standard c++ lib, and can be fixed with a gcc, gcc-dev install on the existing dockerfile.