# nodejs v13.10.1 install on alpine

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to  install `nodejs` version `13.10.1` on alpine docker.

What I'm trying:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
ENV ALPINE_MIRROR "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine"
RUN echo "${ALPINE_MIRROR}/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs-current  --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community"
RUN node --version
```

But of course It's installed the current version in edge (where it isn't v13.10.1).

So how can I found and install `nodejs v13.10.1` on alpine docker?

Comment: Different versions, but this solution should still work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53389095/2422776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't look like there is a package `nodejs-current` version `13.10.1` at branch `edge` in `community` or `main`. see: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs-current&branch=edge&repo=community

you can build your own version - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53389225/2087704

you could use the specific image `FROM node:13.10.1-alpine`